How to suppress all log output from gcloud for scripting
I am running the following command to reset the password for a Windows VM and get the results in JSON format:
gcloud compute reset-windows-password \
  VM_NAME \
  --project=PROJECT_ID \
  --quiet \
  --zone=ZONE \
  --format=json \
  --verbosity=none

The following is printed to stdout:
Resetting and retrieving password for [USERNAME] on [VM_NAME]
Updated [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/zones/ZONE/instances/VM_NAME].
{
  "ip_address": "1.2.3.4",
  "password": "XYZ",
  "username": "USERNAME"
}

This is more than the expected JSON, making it difficult to process the output.
What flag am I missing to suppress the first two lines?

On which OS are you running gcloud?

@DazWilkin I am on Linux

There is no gcloud flag to do this. I'm curious.The deleted answer on this page is the advice that I would give, namely to try sending stderr to /dev/null (2>/dev/null)

Unfortunately, I already tried that - it appears that both the informational notice as well as the JSON are output to the same stream (don't remember whether both were sent to stdout or both to stderr).

Yes, then, I think this is a bug in gcloud and you should consider filing it as an issue on https://issuetracker.google.com. As you expect, the JSON output should be to stdout and the extraneous (non-JSON) output to stderr
